# SDL with OSX without xcode

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, linker, sdl

UPDATE 2
The compiletor found SDL.H with the following command:

```
g++ \
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2/ -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE \
-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-framework,Cocoa \
sdltest.cpp
```

Could someone please explain what the code above says?!

This is my new errors, I realize that I dont compile any other .cpp than my own, should've  I do that?

```
sdltest.cpp:10:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SDL_WM_SetCaption'
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("SDL Test", "SDL Test");
    ^
sdltest.cpp:13:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SDL_SetVideoMode'
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, 0);
                          ^
sdltest.cpp:19:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SDL_DisplayFormat'
    SDL_Surface* bg = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
                      ^
sdltest.cpp:55:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SDL_UpdateRect'
            SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

END OF UPDATE 2

UPDATE 1

I now compile with

```
g++ \
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
-std=c++11 \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/-lSDL2 -framework Cocoa \
lesson01.cpp
```

The output is

```
2 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
 (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

END OF UPDATE 1

I just installed SDL(as a framework) for the first time and I have some problem to link it correctly!

I compile with

```
g++ \
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
-std=c++11 \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -lSDL2 -framework Cocoa \
lesson01.cpp
```

Which return

```
ld: library not found for -lSDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The path seems to be correct since

```
ls /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers | grep SDL.h
```

return

```
SDL.h
```

My Code:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
   return 0
}
```

If I use

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
```

instead, the compiler return

```
lesson01.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'SDL/SDL.h' file not found
```

What can I do to fix this?

Should it be SDL.H or SDL/SDL.h?

I prefer to work via terminal so Xcode is not an option!

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit too much of a mess here to go over everything, but here's something...

You need to decide if you are using SDL 1.2 or SDL 2.0.  They are distinct libraries and come in separate frameworks.  Your compile errors with `SDL_WM_SetCaption` etc. are from code which uses SDL 1.2.

Also decide if you will use a framework for SDL or if you will link to the lib itself (e.g. -lSDL).

Including SDL.h is more portable than SDL/SDL.h.  You just need to make sure that you specify the header search path (with -I).

Comment: I do not understand the third paragraphs!

I have installed a framework! Does that imply that I do not have to link to the library?

Comment: The difference in linking is simply the command you use.  For normal library linking (e.g. to link to libSDL.a), use the `-lSDL` argument to the linker.  If you have installed the framework, then use `-framework SDL` instead, just as you've done for the Cocoa framework.